# Matlab Matrix one-to-one correspondence index

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a small code below for one-to-one correspondence index of the img matrix

```
for k = 1:length(I)
    img(I(k),J(k)) = 0;   
end
```

Now, I hope to get rid of for loop, but I cannot find proper matlab syntax to realize it.

```
img(I(1:length(I)), J(1:length(I)),1:3) = 0;
```

is not one-to-one correspondence index. Any help to realize the same function is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing in a linear fashion along multiple dimensions can be done using the `sub2ind` function:

```
img(sub2ind(size(img), I, J(1:length(I))) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to get this done:

```
ind = sparse(I, J, 1, size(img,1), size(img,2)) == 1;
img(ind) = 0;
```

The first line of code generates a sparse matrix where the row values stored in `I` and the column values stored in `J` set the matrix values to 1, and we ensure that this is the same size as your image.  We also convert to a logical array by equating the statement with 1.  When you're done, simply use the result to index into your actual array and set the values to 0.

If you have a multi-channel matrix, you can do this temporally by making a call to [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
img(repmat(ind, [1 1 size(img,3)])) = 0;
```